# Can I convert a .ConvertToProvider from Func<object, object> to a more precise type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, type-conversion, func

My table `T_SHIP` has a column `FULL_TANK`, containing "Y" if the ship's fuel tank is full, "N" if it isn't, and `Null` if the ship doesn't have a tank, such as a sailing ship.

I define an entity property for that column as such:

```cs
p_etbTable.Property(t => t.HasFullTank).HasColumnName("FULL_TANK")
                                       .HasColumnType("varchar(1)")
                                       .HasConversion(ConversionsHelper.BooleanToY_N);
```

with `BooleanToY_N` a simple `ValueConverter` object:

```cs
public static ValueConverter<bool?, string> BooleanToY_N =
        new ValueConverter<bool?, string>(b => b.HasValue ? (b.Value ? "Y" : "N") : null,
                                          s => s == "Y");
```

In my code, I want to be able to access the values "Y" and "N" directly from `BooleanToY_N`, as an alternative to constants.

```cs
IConventionAnnotation z_annConverterHasFullTank = 
            ((IConventionAnnotatable)new MyDbContext().Model
                                        .GetEntityTypes()
                                        .FirstOrDefault(et => et.ClrType == typeof(TShip))
                                        .GetProperties()
                                        .First(pr => pr.Name == nameof(TShip.HasFullTank)))
                                        .GetAnnotation(nameof(EF_Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter));
EF_Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter<bool?, string> z_vcoConverterHasFullTank =
            (EF_Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter<bool?, string>)z_annConverterHasFullTank.Value;

Func <object, object> z_funConversionHasFullTank = z_vcoConverterHasFullTank.ConvertToProvider.;
```

and then use `z_funConversionHasFullTank.Invoke()` by passing it `false` or `true` to get "N" or "Y", respectively, then use `.ToString()` to convert it to a string.

This works quite well, but to simplify the use of `z_funConversionHasFullTank`, I'd like to define it as `Func<bool?, string>`.

When I do, the compiler informs me that it cannot convert `Func<object, object>` to `Func<bool?, string>`. Still, since there's a `Func<bool?, string>` in there I feel I should be able to get it out. Does anyone have an idea how that could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is of the wrong type, must be:

```
ValueConverter<bool?, string?>
```

Because the string can also be null. Then it has a bug, it won't return `null` when the provider (string) is null but `false` instead:

```
new ValueConverter<bool?, string?>(
    b => b.HasValue ? (b.Value ? "Y" : "N") : null, 
    s => s == null ? null : s == "Y"
);
```

(Or `s => s == null ? null : (bool?)s == "Y"` for earlier C# versions).

Finally, you're right in that `ConvertToProvider` is a `Func<object?, object?>` and that you can't cast that to `Func<bool?, string?>`, but luckily there's also a `ConvertToProviderExpression` which is an `Expression<Func<bool?, string?>>`:

```
Func<bool?, string?> toProvider = z_vcoConverterHasFullTank.
    ConvertToProviderExpression.Compile();
```

Comment: Hm, you're quite right about that first point. I'll have to check it out. Also, thanks for the main point! It works great!

Comment: By the way, for those who (like me) still use C#8, `s => s == null ? null : s == "Y"` won't work there. I tried `s => s == null ? null : (bool?)(s == "Y")`

Comment: Also, are you sure the converter should use `string?` ? Apparently in C# `string` objects can be `null`, so the question mark seems redundant here. (I seem to remember it's somewhat different in VB, but thankfully I'm doing this in C#.)

Comment: Yeah that's nullable reference types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types Something that helps you write more robust code.

Comment: Very interesting. I don't think I can include it in our current projects in a pinch, but what gets the code more robust is generally welcome.